# Overfull \hbox in C++ code (listing-package)

Tags: listings

I currently have a problem with writing C++ in latex. I have a very long string of text inside my code, that interferes with the space.

[image]

So how do I fix this??

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
    frame=tb, % draw a frame at the top and bottom of the code block
    tabsize=4, % tab space width
    showstringspaces=false, % don't mark spaces in strings
    numbers=left, % display line numbers on the left
    commentstyle=\color{green}, % comment color
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}, % keyword color
    stringstyle=\color{red} % string color
}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++]
while(again == 1)
    { //again er defineret som 1, loekken koeres igen.
    cout << "Velkommen til BMI beregneren!" << endl;
    cout << "\nEr du en mand eller kvinde? Tast 1 for mand, tast 2 for kvinde" << endl;
    cin >> sex;
    cout << "Indtast din hojde i cm." << endl;
    cin >> height;
    cout << "Indtast din vaegt i KG." << endl;
    cin >> weight;
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Use `listings`' `breaklines` option.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. How do I use the "breakline" option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `breaklines` option, pointed out by Jubobs, works indeed and without any warnings. Here is how you can do it:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
    frame=tb, % draw a frame at the top and bottom of the code block
    tabsize=4, % tab space width
    showstringspaces=false, % don't mark spaces in strings
    numbers=left, % display line numbers on the left
    commentstyle=\color{green}, % comment color
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}, % keyword color
    stringstyle=\color{red} % string color
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,breaklines]
while(again == 1)
    { //again er defineret som 1, loekken koeres igen.
    cout << "Velkommen til BMI beregneren!" << endl;
    cout << "\nEr du en mand eller kvinde? Tast 1 for mand, tast 2 for kvinde" << endl;
    cin >> sex;
    cout << "Indtast din hojde i cm." << endl;
    cin >> height;
    cout << "Indtast din vaegt i KG." << endl;
    cin >> weight;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]